# jax-rs Download file from server

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am trying to download a file from the server from a rest request. The request is sent, everything seems fine but then I get: 
`org.jboss.resteasy.spi.WriterException: java.io.IOException: Stream is already closed.`

I think it might be because JSF is processing the response afterwards. Usually I use: `facesContext.responseComplete();`
But with a REST request I do not have access to facesContext (it is null).

Here is my java code:

```
response.setContentType(pieceJointe.getContentType());
response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + pieceJointe.getNom() +"\"");
        if (file.exists()) {
            FileInputStream fi;
            try {
                fi = new FileInputStream(file);
                ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

                int b = fi.read();

                while (b != -1) {
                    os.write(b);
                    b = fi.read();
                }

                os.flush();
                os.close();
                fi.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                   
        }
```

What am I doing wrong ? :s

Thanks !

Comment: Try not to close response output stream. You usually don't need to do it since it wasn't you who opened it.

Comment: Okay thanks, that resolved the issue of the closed stream. But the file is still not downloaded. Nothing happens :s

Comment: And try to set content type "application/octet-stream"

Comment: Still the same, nothing is happening. Is this linked to the response ?
Because of the fact that it is a rest request I get the response this way:
     

`public String downloadJustificatif(@PathParam("id")Integer id, @Context HttpServletResponse response, @Context HttpServletRequest req){...}`

Comment: For JAX-RS it probably make sence to check this link http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jax-rs-download-file/ . There are lots of examples

Comment: Thank you for the help. I actually already checked this link. The problem is that in the examples you have to specify in Produces which type of file you want to download. And in my code in can be any type of file. I tried to use octet-stream but this didn't work neither :(

Comment: Did you try not te specify @Produces at all? Also in your example you have return type String, shouldn't it be Response?

Comment: Yeah right now it is string but I tried with Response too. I tried without Produces also. I don't get any error but the file is not downloading.

Comment: I think the problem is that JSF is doing other stuff with the response after my method and this is ruining everything. In the other working examples of my application there is: `facesContext.responseComplete();` which denies JSF to do stuff with the response but since I use rest, facescontext isn't active and I can't use this :s

Comment: But is your request handles via Faces servlet also?

Comment: No, it is handled with resteasy. Actually, when I copy the rest url and put it in the nav bar of Chrome, it downloads the file. So maybe the problem comes from the ajax call inside my js file ?

Comment: Since it works with regular request 99% problem is in ajax call :)

Comment: k so what I didi is window.location = myRestUrl and it works now haha wtf. Anyway, thanks for your help ;)